# On-Demand Expression to limit max monthly data

Tags: spotfire

I have a column of data [Sales ID] that bringing in duplicate data for an analysis. My goal is to use the data on demand to pull unique sales ID's for the max day of every month in the analysis only (instead of daily). Im basically trying to get it to only pull in unique sales ID values for the last the day of every month in the analysis ,and if the current day is the last day so far, then it should pull that in. So it should pull in the MAX date in any given month. Please how do i write an expresion with the [Sales ID] column and [Sales_Date_Time ] in data on demand  to acieve this?

I have attached a screenshot of  the data, and there is and asterix next to the data/rows that should only be pulled in.

Thanks in advance[sales Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sJJP.png)

Comment: Any help with this please??